# adding fade to change background with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code for changing a divs background image with jquery, i need help to add a fade to the code so the image change with some effect

this is the code

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    var images = ['blured/1.jpg','blured/2.jpg'];
    var i = 0;
    var timeoutVar;

    function changeBackground() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutVar); // just to be sure it will run only once at a time

        jQuery('#maincont').css('background-image', function() {
            if (i >= images.length) {
               i=0;
            }
            return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';      
        });

        // call the setTimeout every time to repeat the function
        timeoutVar = setTimeout(changeBackground, 6000);
    }

    // Call it on the first time and it will repeat
    changeBackground();        
});
```

Any help will be great!
i need to just change the background image, without fading the inside divs, this is the html

```
   <div class="maincont" id="maincont">

   <div class="containersrch">

   <h1 class="lagro">some title</h1>

   <div class="joinus">

   <span><a href="join.php">JOIN</a></span>

   </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: Add `fadeIn()` after `.css`.

Comment: Would be nice if you post your html. Also have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp   It will give you idea

Comment: its a background image of a div, that im changing the background image url, this code works but the images change from one to another without any effect, and its not nice, i want to fade from one to another

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
$(function(){
  var imgId = $('#maincont'), imgCount = 1, imgLast = 2;
  setInterval(function(){
    imgId.fadeOut('slow', function(){
      if(++imgCount > imgLast)imgCount = 1;
      imgId.css('background', "url('blured/"+imgCount+".jpg')");
      imgId.fadeIn('slow');
    });
  }, 6000);
});
```

Now you can have multiple images, just change `imgLast` to the last number and make sure they have the correct URLs in your `blured` folder. Of course, the code above assumes you are using `.jpg`. I actually recommend the lossless compression of `.png`, but it won't matter if it's the image was taken as a `.jpg`.

Comment: something like that, but with that code, the hole div dissapears when changing images, i just need to change the background, and the content of the div actually stays there without fading, im uploading the html now